# Bamboo usage on elixir

Tags: elixir, bamboo

I have the following coniguration in my releases.exs

```
  config :botclient, MyAPP.Mailer,
   adapter: Bamboo.SendGridAdapter,
   api_key: System.get_env("sendgrid_key"),
   hackney_opts: [
     recv_timeout: :timer.minutes(1),
     connect_timeout: :timer.minutes(1),
     ssl_options: [
       versions: [:"tlsv1.2"]
     ]
   ]
```

Whenever I try to send an email, I’m always getting the following message with or without the hackney_opts

`(Bamboo.ApiError) {:options, {:sslv3, {:versions, [:"tlsv1.2", :"tlsv1.1", :tlsv1, :sslv3]}}}`

I have tried to read through the documentation to check whether I’m missing something but there’s nothing more in terms of configuring Bamboo to use SSL. I will appreciate any form of assistance